# CPU utilization = 101?

Tags: linux, process, ps, process-management, cpu-usage

I don't understand how can the CPU utilization of my Linux system be `101` for a process on Linux system. What does the `%CPU` actually indicate if it is not percentage utilization?

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME  COMMAND
ubuntu    2504  101 89.3 70072464 56086520 pts/1 Rl+ 18:40 277:26 python xyz.py
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [top output: cpu usage > 100%](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34435/top-output-cpu-usage-100) Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145247/70524

Comment: You have multiple CPUs (cores), so its a percentage of all the available CPUs. For a quad core system, thats 400%